# issue with Laravel login form return false but redirect as true

Tags: php, laravel-authentication, laravel-10

The issue is that when a user logs in from the login page, they are redirected to the home page ("/"), but the application is not recognizing them as logged in.

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $admin = taxiUser::where('email', $credentials['email'])
        ->where('password', $credentials['password'])->first();
    
    if ($admin) {
        Auth::login($admin);
        return redirect('/')
            ->with('success', 'You have been logged in successfully!');
    }
    
    // Check if login credentials are being received correctly
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
        ->withErrors([
        'email' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `->where('password', $credentials['password'])` Are you using plain text passwords in your app? (If so: don't!)

Comment: @brombeer i didn't hash it when i inserted